# Why is my tensorflow1.0 network's cost NOT decreasing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am new to tensorflow. I was trying to train a network on the beast_cancer dataset (30 features) using tensorflow 1.1.15

My network architecture is as follows:

input_layer[30] --> hidden1[32] -->hidden2[16] --> output[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUaZP.png)

Activation Functions:
hidden1: relu
hidden2: relu
output : sigmoid

The cost function I am using is "tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits"
But the cost is not decreasing at all. It remains the same for all iterations.

Here is my code

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf

data = load_breast_cancer()
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data.data, data.target, test_size=0.296, random_state=0)

n_input = 30
n_hide1 = 32
n_hide2 = 16
n_output = 1

weight_map = {
        "h1": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=(n_input, n_hide1))),
        "h2": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=(n_hide1, n_hide2))),
        "out": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=(n_hide2, n_output)))
}

bias_map = {
        "h1": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=(n_hide1, ))),
        "h2": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=(n_hide2, ))),
        "out": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=(n_output, ))),
}


def forward_propagation(x_inp, weights, biases):
    h1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(x_inp, weights["h1"]), biases["h1"]))
    h2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(h1, weights["h2"]), biases["h2"]))
    out = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(h2, weights["out"]), biases["out"]))
    return out


ALPHA = 0.01
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 30])
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None, ])

# STEP1: forward propagation
predictions = forward_propagation(x, weight_map, bias_map)

# STEP2: calculate cost func
cost = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=predictions, labels=y)
cost_reduce_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cost)

# STEP3: backward propagation
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=ALPHA)
optimize = optimizer.minimize(cost_reduce_mean)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    num_iter = 10
    for iteration in range(num_iter):
        c, _ = sess.run([cost_reduce_mean, optimize], feed_dict={x: x_train, y: y_train})
        print("ITER[{}]: {}".format(iteration, c))
```

This is the output I am getting:
Absolutely no change in cost
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUaZP.png)

Comment: If you are new to TensorFlow, why are you using 1.15? It has been deprecated for a while now, you should begin learning with TensorFlow 2.11 which is the current version

Comment: Yes I am aware, I'm following an old MOOC that still uses tensorflow v1. Can you tell me what's wrong with the code?